# HTML page doesn't fit mobile device screen

Tags: html, css, mobile

Here is my HTML :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        .screen {
            font-size: 0.5em;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: red;
            position: absolute;
            width: 8em;
            height: 19em;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        .screen .main {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="screen">
        <div class="main">Ut enim benefici liberalesque sumus, non ut exigamus gratiam (neque enim beneficium faeneramur sed natura propensi ad liberalitatem sumus), sic amicitiam non spe mercedis adducti sed quod omnis eius fructus in ipso amore inest, expetendam putamus.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Although my meta tag for the viewport scaled to device-width, this page doesn't fit the screen : there are still white borders (on my Galaxy S3). I want it to be totally red.

What do I have to do to make this page fit totally my screen ? (and most devices' screens)

I'm a total newbie in mobile development, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in addition to **BenM**'s answer, set this in your css to remove the default style from browsers

```
html, body {
     font-size: 40px;      
     margin:0; /* remove default margin */
     padding:0; /* remove default padding */
     width:100%; /* take full browser width */
     height:100%; /* take full browser height*/
}
```

so complete css should :

```
  .screen {
                font-size: 0.5em;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: red;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100% /* BenM mentioned this in answer*/
                height: 100%; /* take full browser height */
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
            }

  .screen .main {
                width: 100%; /* <--now this takes full browser dimension  */
                height: 100%; /* <--now this takes full browser dimension  */
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the width of `.screen` to `8em`, update that to `100%`:

```
.screen {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 19em;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

You'll also (probably, unless you're using a CSS reset) need to remove the `margin` and `padding` on the `body`:

```
body {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```